# Have you found "From Portfolio to Profit Engine" helpful?

Tags: web, learning

This is not a pitch and I am in no way affiliated with the author of the e-book/training package, *From Portfolio to Profit Engine*. My difficulty is that I cannot find any online reviews of it other than those offered by paid affiliates. It promises a great deal, and I wonder if anyone who has paid for it and does not receive consideration for recommending it, might give indication of its worth.

Have you used *From Portfolio to Profit Engine*? If so, have you found it helpful?

Comment: I'm having trouble seeing how this fits into our FAQ: http://photo.stackexchange.com/faq

Comment: Well, @dpollitt, the tag [web] is defined as "Questions about resources on the World Wide Web or about photography-related web technologies, including those related to promotion of a photography business." This is a question about resources on the World Wide Web having to do with photography, "related to promotion of a photography business." Seems pretty clear to me, and a reasonable question.

Comment: This isn't the place to really debate a questions on-topic-ness or not(http://meta.photo.stackexchange.com/ is). But having a Web tag does not make any and all things relating to it on topic. This is a question about opinions or "reviews" of a product. It would be hard to give factual answers, and I believe that is why it is off topic here. The community decides if it is on or off topic though, so time will tell.

Comment: Fine. I posted it because there is a tag for it, @dpollitt, and I read the FAQ and it's pretty clearly not included in any of the "not appropriate here" categories. I grant it can lead to some chattiness or open-ended discussion, but that does happen here. The FAQ never says anything about reviews, and people post questions here for review-type information about specific products all the time, and get loads of great answers. I was only hoping someone here might have used the product and been able to say whether it helps "promotion a photography business" which is what this tag is about.

Comment: I think the appropriate meta discussion is here: http://meta.photo.stackexchange.com/questions/1803/what-about-review-this-item-please-questions (And there isn't super-strong community consensus but it seems to be mildly in favor of allowing questions asking for specific reviews.)

Comment: @dpollitt is definitely correct in saying that the existence of a tag doesn't prove anything; tags are easy to create.

Comment: I think if you modify your question and title to specify that you are interested in "if it helps promotion of a photography business" that will limit your scope and keep the thread much more on topic. Asking specifically for a "review" of anything usually gets voted to close here. Don't take offense.

Comment: There are so many open-ended, review-type questions in [web], and [web] is as big a tag as dozens of others - in fact, most of the tags are on about 50 posts or fewer. I'm not offended, @dpollitt. Your most recent comment was far more helpful than your first. Anyhow, I don't see how a -1 was necessary.

Comment: Somewhat ironically, I don't think this is really about the web at all, but rather about the training program, which happens to be offered via the web. I would maybe tag it `training`, except apparently we don't have that, so maybe [tag:learning]?

Comment: Oh, I didn't see [learning] - thanks. Well, it's about the web in as much as it's about a product for developing a portfolio site. But [learning] definitely works. Thanks, @mattdm!

Answer (score 3):

I have not used it, have just looked at the sample chapters.  A few thoughts, both pro and con:

- the author has a photography business and (slow-loading flash) website.  If you like the look of her website, it would most likely use the principles she describes in the e-book.  So you may be able to judge the value of the ebook by the quality of her website, assuming she practices what she preaches
- the blogs that have affiliate links - if they are photographers, do they have websites, and do they appear to have used the ideas from the ebook? Hard to tell perhaps, not knowing exactly what's in the ebook, but do you at least like their sites?  (I looked at one, and in fact I thought it was pretty good to be honest, and the review seemed genuine to me)
- the cost at the moment is $159.  If you are a professional, and one of her tips brings you one client, it's probably worth the cost
- OTOH, there is so much free information on the web, even if not photography website specific.  I doubt she's discovered anything that isn't generally known.  Still, tips on pricing, identifying your client base, and so forth, that are photography-specific, might be valuable
- the sample chapters don't really inspire me, so hard to tell what the rest of it is like
- she has her email listed and seems to welcome questions.  Might offer a refund if you're not satisfied